# How can I import a module that is in GHCi paths?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I seem unable to import a module when executing `ghci` directly, however I am able to load the module when executing `ghci xmonad.hs`.

**Directory tree:**

```
.
├── ghcid.sh
├── lib
│   ├── FocusWindow.hs
│   ├── MiddleColumn.hs
│   ├── Readme.md
│   └── TAGS
├── Readme.md
├── TAGS
├── xmonad2.hs
├── xmonad.errors
├── xmonad.hs
├── xmonad.state
├── xmonad.state.backup
└── xmonad-x86_64-linux
```

**.ghci**

```
:set -Wall
:set -i:lib
```

**ghci prompt:**

```
Prelude> :show paths
current working directory: 
  /home/chris/.xmonad
module import search paths:
  .
  lib
Display all 2040 possibilities? (y or n)
Prelude> import FocusWindow

<no location info>: error:
    Could not find module ‘FocusWindow’
    It is not a module in the current program, or in any known package.
```

**ghci xmonad.hs prompt**

```
GHCi, version 8.0.1: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Loaded GHCi configuration from /home/chris/.xmonad/.ghci
[1 of 3] Compiling FocusWindow      ( lib/FocusWindow.hs, interpreted )
[2 of 3] Compiling MiddleColumn     ( lib/MiddleColumn.hs, interpreted )
[3 of 3] Compiling Main             ( xmonad.hs, interpreted )
Ok, modules loaded: MiddleColumn, FocusWindow, Main.
*Main> import FocusWindow
*Main FocusWindow> :show paths
current working directory: 
  /home/chris/.xmonad
module import search paths:
  .
  lib
```

Comment: Have you tried `:load xmonad` before doing the imports?

Comment: That works, thanks. I still want to know why though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only import modules that are from some known package or which have been loaded. When you run `ghci xmonad.hs`, it loads `xmonad.hs` and any modules needed by it. When you run `ghci`, it doesn't load anything by default.

You can load your module alone by running `:load FocusWindow`, or `:l FocusWindow` for short. That will automatically also "import" that module in a special way (specifically: making all names available, even un-exported ones), and you will also be able to do normal imports of modules used by `FocusWindow`.

It would probably be a nice feature for ghci's `import` support to try loading unknown modules before complaining. I suspect a patch adding that feature would be accepted.